# HyperLoglog Spring Key Operation

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

I have following code snippet to test if I can add HLL values in  Redis, This test pass, but when I verify it from redis-command-line, I did not see "HLLTEST" key, instead I found weird key as you can see from the following output.
Is there something wrong with usage of  HyperLogLogOperations,

```
@Test
    public void whenHllRecord_thenCount() throws Exception {
        hyperLogLogOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHyperLogLog();

        hyperLogLogOperations.add("HLLTEST:1010", 1);
        hyperLogLogOperations.add("HLLTEST:1010",2);

        long size = hyperLogLogOperations.size("HLLTEST:1010");

        assertEquals("Size: "+size, size, 2);
    }
```

**Redis-Command-Line**

```
redis:6379> keys *
 1) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0cHLLTEST:1010"
redis:6379> pfcount HLLTEST:1010
(integer) 0
```

RedisConf

```
 @Bean
   public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
      final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
      template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
      template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
      return template;
   }
```

Comment: You want to check out the docs about [Serialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer). `RedisTemplate` defaults to the JDK Serializer. Use `StringRedisSerializer` to store data as plain `String`.

Comment: I have used GenericToStringSerializer and StringRedisSerializer both, but Having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to assing key serializer. After setting it as following it works,

```
  @Bean
   public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
      final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
      template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());

     //template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));

      template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
      template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

      return template;
   }
```